# Dealing with input null values for variables/parameters

Tags: sql

Hi so I am having a little difficulty in understanding how to deal with non-answer/blank inputs from a user. Let us use the assumption that @Number can have value from 0 to 10. The user may or may not input multiple numbers (ex. 0,1,2,3,4,5) (ex. ''). I then insert the inputed numbers into a temporary table called #NumberList. I then select the name that corresponds to the inputed number using an inner join. There is a table called "toys" that contain numbers ranging from 0 to 1,000,000.

The code below is a representative of the actual code that I wrote.  How would I modify the code so that if there was a blank, it would contain all the values (0 to 10)?  Basically, if there is no input/blank, then the parameter is disregarded (the result should be 1,000,000 toy names).

```
DECLARE @Number NVARCHAR(100) =  '' 

~~ I created a temporary table called #NumberList (not shown) that contains all the inputed numbers~~

SELECT Name
FROM Toys AS t
INNER JOIN #NumberList AS nl
ON t.Number = nl.Number
WHERE nl.Number IS NULL OR t.Number = nl.Number
```

The WHERE statement is incorrect but I honestly have no idea how to write it so that a blank input would just be all numbers (0 to 10). I imagine the temporary table has no values if there is no input, so is there a way to modify the code so that the temporary table has all the values (0 to 10)?

Comment: Typically the best approach from a performance standpoint is to have two queries: one with the `JOIN`, the other without (use an `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #NumberList)` to distinguish). While you *can* make it all one query and have a `JOIN` that effectively does nothing, this is clumsy and leads to more expensive query plans (if only because row estimates will be off). (Incidentally, the `JOIN` can be written more simply as `WHERE t.Number IN (SELECT Number FROM #NumberList)`.)

Comment: Should you find yourself bored and with some minutes to spare for reading, [this article](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) comes highly recommended for the general case of flexible queries.

Comment: If *what* were a blank then *what would contain all values?  I'm a little lost on the question.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets you what you need.

```
SELECT  Name
INTO    #Results
FROM    Toys AS t
        INNER JOIN #NumberList AS nl ON t.Number = nl.Number
WHERE   1 = 1;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Results
    (
        Name
    )
    SELECT  Name
    FROM    Toys AS t
    WHERE   1 = 1;
END;

SELECT name  FROM #Results  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want an `or` condition?

```
SELECT t.Name
FROM Toys t
INNER JOIN #NumberList AS nl
WHERE EXITS (SELECT 1
             FROM #NumberList nl
             WHERE t.Number = nl.Number
            ) OR
      NOT EXIST (SELECT 1
                 FROM #NumberList nl
                );
```